# using resource key MVC 3 ASPX FILE

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using mVC3 With aspx engine,

```
<%html.TextBoxFor(m=m.Code,new {maxlength="6"})%>
```

i wana take the vlaue "6" from  resource file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a global resource file (in your `App_GlobalResources` folder) and then use the strongly typed class to access values:

```
<%= html.TextBoxFor(m = m.Code, new { maxlength = MyResources.MaxLength }) %>
```